# Get the name of a running Java program from C# (like the process name for .NET apps)

Tags: c#, java, .net, process

I need to get the name of the Java program thats being executed by Java, from a C# program. I have no access to the Java program (aka I'm not the one who wrote it, so I can't make it communicate with my C# program.) Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a command line tool that comes with the JDK called 'jps'. jps -v shows all the arguments you have passed to java.

You can call jps from c# and then read the output.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I don't believe so and let me explain why:

on your root machine, if you use a process explorer you will just see the JVM (java virtual machine) and not what is happening inside it. the herarchy would actually be Root > Java VM > Java VM process.  hope that logic helps you find your solution if there is one.

Comment: the only way I think its possible is if you detect whenever a .jar is launched and then record it that way, but you still wont know which process is running which jar if there are more than 1 jars running..